# Get filter value from Syncfusion ExtendedGrid for WPF

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, syncfusion

We need to persist the filters (those funnel filtering on header row) in Syncfusion's WPF grid.

How is it possible to read the current filter settings so that we can persist it? And what would be the way to restore those filters programmatically?

Is that even possible?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get the Filters for particular column by using the following code snippet.

Code snippet[C#]:

var Filters = this.SyncGrid.VisibleColumns["CustomerID"].Filters;


And also you can add the Filters for particular column by using the following code snippet.

Code Snippet[C#]:
this.SyncGrid.VisibleColumns["CustomerID"].Filters.Add(new Syncfusion.Windows.Data.FilterPredicate()
{
    FilterValue = 2,
    PredicateType = Syncfusion.Windows.Data.PredicateType.Or,
    FilterBehavior = Syncfusion.Linq.FilterBehavior.StringTyped,
    FilterType = Syncfusion.Linq.FilterType.Equals
});


Note: Here CustomerID is the MappingName of GridDataVisibleColumn
```